# MYSQL SELECT query: How to concatenate 4 tables with AND and OR conditions?

Tags: mysql

I have four MySQL tables:

**usuarios** (have the list of all users and their personal information)

**roles** (have the list of available roles in the site, that determines their permissions)

**rolesUsuarios** (links each user with their roles. They can have more than one)

**cursos** (have the list of courses of the site with each course description)

**cursosUsuarios** (links each user with all the courses where they are enrolled)

I want to make a SELECT query that shows me for a specific user, all their personal information, the roles he has and the courses where he's enrolled.

I've created this query that does work:

```
SELECT  usuarios.userID, usuarios.userEmail, usuarios.userApellido, usuarios.userNombres, 
                    usuarios.userDNI, usuarios.userFechaGeneracion,
                    rolesUsuarios.userID, rolesUsuarios.nombreRol,
                    cursosUsuarios.userID, cursosUsuarios.cursoID, 
                    cursos.cursoID, cursos.nombreCurso, cursos.cursoYear, cursos.cursoMes, 
                    cursos.modalidadCurso,
            GROUP_CONCAT(cursos.nombreCurso, ':', cursosUsuarios.cursoID ORDER BY cursosUsuarios.cursoID SEPARATOR ',') AS 'cursos'
            FROM usuarios JOIN rolesUsuarios JOIN cursosUsuarios JOIN cursos
            WHERE usuarios.userID='10'
            AND rolesUsuarios.userID = usuarios.userID
            AND cursosUsuarios.userID = usuarios.userID
            AND cursosUsuarios.cursoID = cursos.cursoID
            GROUP BY usuarios.userID
```

**The problem is that if the user isn't enrolled in any course, it won't show any result. How may I do that?**

These are each tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE roles(
    roleID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombreRol char(50) not null
);

CREATE TABLE usuarios(
    userID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userEmail char(50) null,
    userApellido char(50) null,
    userNombres char(50) null,
    userDNI int(10) null,
    userPass char(65) null,
    userFechaGeneracion char(10) null
);

CREATE TABLE rolesUsuarios (
    rolesUsuariosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    nombreRol char(50) not null
);

CREATE TABLE cursos (
    cursoID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    nombreCurso char(100) not null,
    cursoYear int(4) not null,
    cursoMes char(3) not null,
    cursoFechaInicio char(10) null,
    modalidadCurso char(50) not null
);

CREATE TABLE cursosUsuarios (
    cursosUsuariosID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int not null,
    cursoID int not null
);
```

Comment: you're doing what amounts to an `inner` join - records must exist in the tables on both sides of the join. you need a `left` or `right` join instead. use the proper `select from table1 join table2 join table3`-type syntax, which makes it easy to specify the join type.

Comment: I just don't understand how to change it in such a complex SELECT (at least complex to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this will work:

```
SELECT  usuarios.userID, usuarios.userEmail, usuarios.userApellido, usuarios.userNombres, 
                usuarios.userDNI, usuarios.userFechaGeneracion,
                rolesUsuarios.userID, rolesUsuarios.nombreRol,
                cursosUsuarios.userID, cursosUsuarios.cursoID, 
                cursos.cursoID, cursos.nombreCurso, cursos.cursoYear, cursos.cursoMes, 
                cursos.modalidadCurso,
GROUP_CONCAT(cursos.nombreCurso, ':', cursosUsuarios.cursoID ORDER BY cursosUsuarios.cursoID SEPARATOR ',') AS 'cursos'
FROM usuarios LEFT JOIN rolesUsuarios
    ON usuarios.userID = rolesUsuarios.userID
LEFT JOIN cursosUsuarios 
    ON usuarios.userID = cursosUsuarios.userID
LEFT JOIN cursos
    ON cursosUsuarios.cursoID = cursos.cursoID
WHERE usuarios.userID='10'
GROUP BY usuarios.userID;
```

Also, if you are selecting a single userID in the WHERE clause there is no need for the GROUP BY userID line.